# Posting on social media accounts in React Native APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native app, I get `Message` test and `ImageURL` string from server, which I need to share on FB, TWITTER, GOOGLE AND INSTAGRAM.

Note that, I am looking for libraries that works with both android and ios and able to share to all share media and should give some callback, so that I can get the event whether the image has been posted successfully or not.

I tried searching on net and also tried few libraries also, but I didn't got the expected outcome.

Should I have to use SDK for each social media? let me know your ideas, how should I proceed for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

you can use **`Share`** library of react-native, that will open a dialog to share ***text content containing links*** and other text stuff.

docs will be available [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share).

And if you want to share other stuff too, then you can use [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) module, that provide to share **text + multimedia** content on social apps.

If you want to share only text content then i recommend you to use **`Share`** library of react-native.

Comment: Thank you , but I see the above library only supports sharing on installed apps, but what if the FB, or Google app is not installed? This doesn't allow the case I think.

Comment: Then you need to install sdk for the same, like for fb share you meed to use fb-sdk.

Comment: And what about for Twitter, Google and Instagram.

Comment: For that i also need to reasearch, but for all.this you also need to do authentication with each sdk.